# Solve complex matrix equation

Tags: matlab, matrix, equation, equation-solving

I have a complex equation involving matrices:

```
R = expm(X)*A + (expm(X)-I)*inv(X)*B*U;
```

where `R`, `B` and `U` are known matrices.
`I` is an identity matrix.

I need to solve for `X`. Is there any way to solve this in MATLAB?

Comment: Is `A` supposed to be one of the known matrices?

Comment: Yes. A is a known Matrix as well.

Answer (score 0):

If your equation is nonlinear and you have access to MATLAB optimization toolbox you can use the fsolve function (You can still use it for a linear equation, but it may not be the most efficient approach).  You just need to reformat your equation into the form F(x) = 0, where x is a vector or a matrix.  For example, if X is a vector of length 2:

Define your function to solve:

```
function F = YourComplexEquation(X)
Fmatrix = expm(X)*A + (expm(X)-I)*inv(X)*B*U - R
% This last line is because I think fsolve requires F to be a vector, not a matrix
F = Fmatrix(:);
```

Then call fsolve with an initial guess:

```
X = fsolve(@YourComplexEquation,[0;0]);
```